# TypeORM getManager.query is not working but if i use the query to terminal it work

Tags: sql, postgresql, key, nestjs, typeorm

I have a strange Error. I was using TypeORM and postgresql. If I try to UPDATE in terminal it work fine.

[image]

But If I code with getManager.query, it appear this error

```
await getManager().query(`
      UPDATE game_ranking
      SET
      count = 77
      WHERE "gameId"='bfff38a8-1ee6-4475-9efd-55155599da38'
      `);
```

[image]

I don't understand why this error appear. There are no duplicate key on my table.

[image]

[image]

Is this a TypeORM Error?
Or is there a solution?

Comment: Please post the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
await getManager().query(`
  UPDATE game_ranking
  SET
  count = 77
  WHERE gameId="bfff38a8-1ee6-4475-9efd-55155599da38"
  `);
```

Hard to say why TypeORM shows an error like this, but just try to run code in this format, because format `WHERE "column"='value'` is not returning valid data even in mysql cli

Comment: Thanks. I try but still the same problem. I think I'll switch to Prisma.